# Multiprocessing in tkinter not getting text output in output_box

Tags: tkinter, python-multiprocessing

What i want to do is that when i press the scrape button, it scrapes several websites using mutliprocessing and puts the output in the text box provided by tkinter. Below is high level interpretation of my code.

```
import multiprocessing
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


def do():
    global arr
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(f,arr)
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()


root = tk.Tk()
output_box=tk.Text(root)
output_box.pack()
def f(x):
    global output_box
    output_box.insert("end-1c",str(x))
    print(x)
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    arr=list(range(10))
    scrape_button=Button(root,text='Scrape!',command=do)
    scrape_button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

the code when executed, gives the tkinter window with the button and text window. But when i click scrape, x is printed in stdout but not in output_box. What should i do so that i get the intended output(what we insert in the output_box in the function f) in my text box?

Comment: What do you mean by "high level interpretation"? Does this code accurately reproduce the same behavior?

Comment: sorry for my bad english...what i meant that resolving issue in above code would resolve my original problem